# Computing $\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 x^{\frac{1}{1-n}}\left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in

$$ \underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 f(x,n) dx = \underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 x^{\frac{1}{1-n}}\left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1}dx, $$

where $q\in(0,1)$. Numerical computation suggests that it is 0.

My approach so far has been to express the second factor of $f(x,n)$ as a Gauss hypergeometric function.

$$\left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1} = {}_1F_0\left((1-n);(1-q)x^{\frac{1}{1-n}}\right)$$

$$ \int x^\frac{1}{1-n}{}_1F_{0}\left((1-n);(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)dx = {}_2F_{1}\left((1-n);(2-n);(3-n);(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right) $$

I would appreciate any hint, how to compute the limit. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Based on the suggestions below, I apply the Dominated Convergence theorem:

$$\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 f(x,n)dx = \int_{0}^1 \underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim}f(x,n)dx. $$

$\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} x^{\frac{1}{1-n}} = 1$ and $\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1} = 0$. Thus, I conclude that

$$\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\lim} \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 x^{\frac{1}{1-n}}\left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1}dx = 0.$$

Comment: Have you already tried the dominated convergence Theorem?

Comment: I did not! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $t = x^{1+\frac{1}{1-n}} = x^{\frac{2-n}{1-n}}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-n}{2-n}\int_{(1-q)^{n-2}}^1\left(1-(1-q)t^{\frac{1}{2-n}}\right)^{n-1}\:dt \longrightarrow \int_0^10\:dt = 0$$

by dominated convergence since $q\in(0,1)$.

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand why you substitute $x$, but pointing out the dominated convergence theorem was very helpful. When applying the theorem, do I take the limit of the integral's lower bound?

Comment: @Jeff You have to take the limit of the lower bound. You can put the characteristic funtion of the interval $((1-q)^{n-2},1)$ inside the integral and integrate over $(0,1)$ if you like.

Comment: @Jeff you raise a good point! Originally I had no idea if this integral would approach something nonzero and that is the standard technique for computing such things. As it turns out, the integrand behaves like $q^{n-1}$ for large $n$, and with this substitution you can prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} q^{1-n}I_n = 1$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Alright, thanks! Unfortunately, this is all non-standard to me. It would help a lot, if you could elaborate a bit how the substitution works; perhaps using the function below that should go towards something nonzero in $n$ (I suspect that the limit is 1): $$ f(x,n) = q^{-n}x^\frac{1}{1-n}\left(1-(1-q)x^\frac{1}{1-n}\right)^{n-1}$$